# vb6 collection exist and boolean value set

Tags: vb6

I am new to vb6 so might be obvious for some of you.I have a collection problem, trying to put items in a collection to then evaluate if the item exists and setting a button to be enabled or  not.

The Code:

```
For Each vBookmark In lstAssign.SelBookmarks

    '---------------------------------------

    'filtering with agency code and crew code.
    sAssignmentValue = lstAssign.columns("AgencyCode").Value & lstAssign.columns("CrewCode").Value
    'Show/hide value depending on crew existance.

        If Not ExistsStartLocation(colParameters, sValue) Then
            bEnableMyButton =  True
            colParameters.Add (sValue)  
        Else
            bEnableMyButton =  False
        End If

    '----------------------------------------

Next


sAssignmentValue = ""
tbrMain.TbrButtonEnabled "XXX", bEnableMyButton


tbrMain.TbrButtonEnabled "YYY", bEnable

Set colStartLocationParameters = Nothing

Exit Sub

Private Function ExistsStartLocation(col As collection, index As Variant) As Boolean

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    Dim v As Variant

    v = col(index)
    ExistsStartLocation = True
    Exit Function

    ErrHandler:
        ExistsStartLocation = False
End Function
```

The problem is at this moment is that I only have  colParameters(index) accessible, so I can't access my collection with a value  "123-ABC" directly. I do not want to add an integer index, I want to keep simply accessing by item value, but my exists method will always return false. therefore always disabling my button.

How does this works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first glance, you should have to do something like this:

```
Private Function ExistsStartLocation(col As collection, val As String) As Boolean
    Dim blnFoundItem As Boolean = False

    For index As Integer = 1 To col.Count
        If col(index) = val Then
            blnFoundItem = True
        End If
    Next

    ExistsStartLocation = blnFoundItem 
End Function
```

Comment: You will have to adapt it, since you didn't post any information about the collection possible methods/properties...

Comment: colParameters.Add (sValue) the string value is a "123-ABC" value with no index so everytime that goes to the method it returns error because it can only be accessed by the col(Index) instead col(Value).

Comment: Ok, I've updated my answer with what you stated... Instead of accessing the value using `col(index).Value = val`, you should use `col(index) = val`

Answer (score 0):

Looping the collection works but is not efficient. If you assign the optional `Key` value in the `Add` method you can also use that as the Index to the `Item` method. In your example it appears you are assigning a string to the collection so the Add method would look something like ...

```
colParameters.Add sValue, sValue
```

- Be aware though that if you are adding duplicate values this won't work. The keys need to be unique.

With the the collection item's key populated you can use a function that leverages the err object. If you try to get a collection item by the key and it exists no error is thrown. If it does not exists err.number 5 is thrown. The new function would be something like this.

```
Public Function ItemExists(ByVal vCollection As Collection, ByVal vKey As String) As Boolean
    Dim varItem As Variant

    On Error Resume Next

    varItem = vCollection.Item(vKey)
    ItemExists = (Err.Number = 0)

End Function
```

Comment: And isn't triggering an error on purpose also not efficient? [source](http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/tech-discussions/298060-performance-degradation-using-error-resume.html)

Comment: @jac I tried this version and looks more clear and I have no problem with throwing an exception in the other side I will get my false boolean which in any case, I want to emulate a key, since I have a grid and my BL is if user selects two items with the same values the button should be disabled. However your solution will enable at some point my button if it happens to click over one item that does not exists in the collection. Thanks anyway.